# How to generate fixed length exponent of a given RSA private key in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, private-key, java-security

I need hex of a RSA private-key exponent to be always of fixed length i.e., 512 bytes. For this the exponent itself should be 2045-2048 characters long. Then only its hex will be of length 512. Here is the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp1 = kpg.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey1 = kp1.getPrivate();

KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
RSAPrivateKeySpec pkSpec1 = keyFac.getKeySpec(privateKey1, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
BigInteger encPrivateKeyExponent = pkSpec1.getPrivateExponent();
String encPrivateKeyExponentHex = encPrivateKeyExponent.toString(16);  // hex of exponent
```

The problem I am facing is this: Every time the code is run, the **encPrivateKeyExponentHex** varies in length (in the range of 509-512 bytes) depending on the length of **encPrivateKeyExponent**. I need the hex length to be exactly 512 bytes everytime. Is there a way to ensure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no BigInteger routine that directly produces a fixed-length radix representation. The easiest approach is to use `.toString(16)` as you do and then pad with leading `0` characters as needed. Or you can write a fixed-length output routine something like:

```
char[] out = new char[512]; // probably best to make 512 a named constant
for( int i = 512; --i >= 0; ){
    out[i] = Character.forDigit (privexpt.intValue()&0xF, 16);
    privexpt = privexpt.shiftRight(4);
}
String result = new String (out);
```

However, two points to be aware of:

- you don't need `KeyFactory` and Spec-class to get the private exponent; the private half of RSA `KeyPair` implements [`java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey.html#getPrivateExponent--)
- if you intend at some future time or other place to do private-key operation(s) for this keypair, saving or transmitting only the private exponent is not a good way. Essentially all RSA implementations for about 30 years do NOT simply do 'c up d mod n' as shown in the first few paragraphs of wikipedia or billions of blogs copied from brief news clippings or exceprts from decades ago, but instead use a more complicated private-key that supports the more efficient 'Chinese Remainder Theorem' computation as explained if you read all of [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29), or look at a text by an author who actually knows about modern cryptography. Java crypto does support RSA-CRT private-keys, like all private-keys, in a industry standard encoding (PKCS8) that is fairly widely (though not universally) supported; this is noted, though not really explained, in javadoc for the top-level interface [`java.security.Key`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html)

Comment: thanks for the approach and suggestions! Will keep in mind.